# What is a difference between an object literal and a class with values in constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor

I've been working on end to end test in testcafe and in their documentation I found following solution for Page Model:

```
class Page {
    constructor () {
        this.nameInput = Selector('#developer-name');
    }
}

export default new Page();
```

I've been doing some research and I cannot get my head around why it is not resolved with an object literal:

```
export const Page = {
    nameInput: Selector('#developer-name');
}
```

What are consequences of using each of them?

Comment: Since `Page` has no methods, a class doesn't make any sense. Even if Page did have methods, it would be easier to define them in the exported object literal than define a class, since the class is only referenced once

Comment: Well, you could do `variable instanceof Page` with the former but not the latter. However, given that you only need a single instance, I'm not sure how much use would that have.

Comment: The class will let you create multiple `Page` instances (although only one is created and exposed in this example), but the object literal only exposes a single instance. You can still have multiple instances with the object literal approach if you change `Page` to a function that returns the object literal (like a DIY constructor): `export const Page = () => ({nameInput: Selector('developer-name')});`

Answer (score 4):

The difference is significant but fundamentally both are JavaScript objects, albeit with different properties and values. Listing all differences on the level of the language would be a long story and you'd be wise to read and understand on [JavaScript prototype-based inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), but the most important differences are:

- `Page` is a prototype object: whenever you create an object of class `Page` with `new Page()`, the constructor function is called with `this` referring to the object being created, not `Page` itself. Any property you access on the object is searched along the so-called "prototype chain", including the so-called prototype object. This prototype object can be accessed with `Page.prototype` and in fact, all methods you define in the class `Page` are also properties of this prototype object. Unlike own properties designed to refer to unique objects or primitives specific to an object, functions in JavaScript don't have to be bound to an object during object or function creation and *can be shared* between objects (belonging to the same class, for instance) and are called on the actual instance, not the prototype to which they may belong. In other words, `this.nameInput` in your constructor actually adds a property named `nameInput` to the object being created with `new Page()`, not the prototype, while the constructor itself (`constructor`) and any non-static methods you might add to `Page` will be added as properties of `Page.prototype`. The constructor is accessed as `Page.prototype.constructor`, by the way, as you'd naturally expect. `Page.prototype.constructor === Page` evaluates to `true`, by the way.
- An expression of the form like `{ nameInput: ... }` creates an object which prototype is `Object.prototype`, in practice the most basic form of object with "no prototype" and thus no superclass or any traits beyond what the fundamental object prototype object could provide. Any properties any such `{ ... }` object may seem to have through its prototype chain, including methods, are properties of `Object.prototype`. This is why you can do `({}).toString()` or `({}).hasOwnProperty("foobar")` without actually having `toString` or `hasOwnProperty` properties in your object -- `toString` and `hasOwnProperty` are properties of `Object.prototype` referring to two distinct methods called `toString` and `hasOwnProperty`, respectively, and JavaScript creates a special property *on your object* called `__proto__` referring to `Object.prototype`. This is how it knows how to "walk the prototype chain". The *names* of functions themselves do not matter like that, by the way -- I may add a property on an object referring to an anonymous function: `var foo = ({}); foo.bar = function() { };` and call said unnamed function with `foo.bar()`.

One mistake you appear to be making is confusing an object of a class with the class, otherwise you wouldn't compare `export default class Page { ... }` to `export const Page = { nameInput: Selector(...) }` -- the former creates a class accessible as `Page` which is used as the prototype object whenever objects of the class are created, while the latter creates an object accessible as `Page` which contains `nameInput` referring to result of evaluating expression `Selector("#developer-name")` (calling `Selector` with the sole argument `"#developer-name"`). *Not* the same thing at all, not to mention that former has `Page` refer to a class (invariably a prototype in JavaScript), while latter has `Page` refer to an object that does not seem to fit the pattern of a class.

The interesting things start when you realize that since a class is an object like any other in JavaScript, any object can be used as a class if you know how prototype-based inheritance works:

```
new (function() { this.nameInput = Selector("#developer-name"); })();
```

What happens here? You create a new object with an unnamed function as the object constructor. The effect is absolutely equivalent to otherwise creating the object with `new Page` with `Page` being your original ES6 class (ECMAScript 6 is the language specification that adds `class` syntax to JavaScript).

You can also do this, again equivalent to if you defined `Page` with `class Page ...`:

```
function Page() {
    this.nameInput = Selector("#developer-name");
}

var foo = new Page();
```

`Page.prototype` will be the prototype object for `foo`, accessible as `foo.__proto__` and otherwise making it possible for you to call instance methods on `foo` like `foo.bar()`, provided you define `bar` property on at least `Page.prototype`:

```
function Page() {
    this.nameInput = Selector("#developer-name");
}

Page.prototype.bar = function() {
    console.log(this.nameInput);
}

var foo = new Page();
foo.bar();
```

In fact, the above is what browser would do internally if it had to interpret the following code:

```
class Page {
    constructor() {
        this.nameInput = Selector("#developer-name");
    }
    bar() {
        console.log(this.nameInput);
    }
}
```

It is beyond the scope of my answer to list differences between the two last approaches (isn't the same thing as the two approaches you proposed), but one difference is that with `class Page ...`, `Page` is not a property of `window` in some user agents while with `function Page ...` it is. It's partly historical reasons, but rest assured that so far defining constructors and prototype using either approach is pretty much the same, although I can imagine smarter JavaScript runtimes will be able to optimize the latter form better (because it's an atomic declaration, and not just a sequence of expressions and statements).

If you understand prototype-based inheritance at the heart of all of this, all your questions about this will fall away by themselves as very few fundamental mechanisms of JavaScript support 99% of its idiosyncrasies. You'll also be able to optimize your object design and access patterns, knowing when to choose ES6 classes, when not to, when using object literals (`{ prop: value, ... }`) and when not to, and how to share fewer objects between properties.

Answer (score 1):

Classes can be thought of as a blueprint, they both provide an object in the end. But as the object literals name implies, you literally create it there and then with this 'literal' syntax. A class however, we would use to instantiate new instances from 1 base blueprint.

```
let x = { myProp: undefined }
let y = { myProp: undefined }

x.myProp = "test";
y.myProp // undefined
```

Here we see we make two separate instances, but we will have to repeat code.

```
class X { }

let x = new X();
let y = new X();
```

A class does not need to repeat the code, as it is all encapsulated in the idea of what X should be, a blueprint.

Similar to above [in the literal] we have two separate instances but it's cleaner, more readable, and any change we wish to make to every instance of this 'X' object can now be changed simply in the class.

There's a plethora of other benefits and even a paradigm dedicated to Object-Oriented Programming, read here for more:
https://www.internalpointers.com/post/object-literals-vs-constructors-javascript

To go further into the constructor question... In other languages we have fields. 
I believe when you assign a field in the constructor, it just creates an underthehood like field (I say underthehood like because JavaScript is prototype based, and the class syntax is syntactical sugar to help write prototypes easier for programmers familiar with class syntax in other languages).

Here is an example in C#.

```
public class X{
   private int y;

   X() {
      this.y = 5;
   }
}
```

It's more a convention to assign fields in the constructor in other languages, so I assume this has something to do with it in JavaScript.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring it as a Class you can later identify what type of object it is with .constructor.name:

```js
class Page {
  constructor () {
    this.nameInput = "something";
  }
  // No comma
  anotherMethod() {
  }
}

const pageClass = new Page();

const pageLiteral = {
  nameInput: "something"
  , // must have a comma
   anotherMethod() {
  }   
}

console.log("Name of constructor for class: ", pageClass.constructor.name); // Page
console.log("Name of constructor for literal: ", pageLiteral.constructor.name); // Object
```